# Wireguard fallback to relay when direct connection is unavailable

Tags: networking, routing, vpn

I have three machines hooked together: A desktop, a laptop, and small public server. The desktop and laptop are usually on NAT-ed networks, while the server has a static IP with publicly accessible ports. By only specifying the server (`10.0.14.0/24`) on both machines, they are able to connect to ping each other (`10.0.14.100/32` and `10.0.14.101/32`, respectively) through it. However, I want the laptop and desktop to connect directly over LAN on the occasion they are both on the same LAN, for obvious performance reasons.

I have already tried putting down an additional `Peer` entry on the laptop and desktop informing them about the other using their fixed private IPs when on the LAN. This prevents the general `10.0.14.0/24` rule from ever taking effect, though.

How can I get the laptop and desktop to connect using a direct connection specified via `Endpoint` when accessible, but fallback to a more general server otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

The small public server will be functioning as a "[Bounce Server](https://github.com/pirate/wireguard-docs/blob/master/README.md#bounce-server)"

According to the "[How Wireguard Routes Packets](https://github.com/pirate/wireguard-docs/blob/master/README.md#how-wireguard-routes-packets)" section of "[Some Unofficial WireGuard Documentation](https://github.com/pirate/wireguard-docs/blob/master/README.md)", setting up a specific route directly to the host (e.g. `10.0.14.100/32`), and a more general route (e.g. `10.0.14.0/24`) should allow the hosts to connect directly to each other, and fallback to routing through the bounce server:

> More specific (also usually more direct) routes provided by other peers will take precedence when available, otherwise traffic will fall back to the least specific route